# Did Donald Trump tell people to "check out" Alicia Machado's sex tape?

Tags: quotes, donald-trump

In the presidential debates, Donald Trump [denied that he told people to "check out sex tape" of Alicia Machado.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nghv7G7vZo) Did he in fact say "check out sex tape" about her?

Comment: I know, low hanging fruit. Still deserves an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, he did. Sept 30th on Twitter.

[Link to tweet (May disappear)](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/781788223055994880?lang=en)
[image: Screen Shot of Tweet.]

> Did Crooked Hillary help disgusting (check out sex tape and past) Alicia M become a U.S. citizen so she could use her in the debate?

Now, we can not be certain that it actually was Trump on the account at that time.  But, if it was not, it was most likely a trusted member of the campaign staff.

Comment: Out of context, seems questionable. In context, not really.

Comment: Also, the alleged sex tape showed her under the covers. i.e. Nothing visible.

Comment: If it was the latter, you'd think he'd disavow them. Then again, Trump will never apologize for *anything*, so...

Comment: Archive tweet link, on the off-chance he develops some shame from this tweet: https://archive.is/U6d0W

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara He's said and done worse and his supporters love him for it. Unlikely.

Comment: @CrisCudmore If Trump is not questioning the authenticity of the post, why are you? No need for disclaimer.

Comment: @ventsyv  Because I am a skeptic, and I must examine all possibilities. Also, the question was directly about Trump denying he said this.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Did you examine the possibility that Trump was replaced by an alien in human body and that he (the alien) did not say that? You are proposing hypotheticals that have no factual support. Nobody has questioned the authenticity of that post, not even Trump.

Comment: Watch the video in the question.  He denies saying "Check out the sex tape".